# Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm making a small game project with a leaderboard table.

I'm trying to get the leaderboard from a mysql database to display using jQuery ajax and PHP but its giving me an error message.

My syntax seems to look fine so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
$("#leader-btn").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "leaderboard.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(response) {
            $("#leaderboard-box").html(response);
            $("#leaderboard-box").css("display","block");
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery, and also have you wrapped this in `$(document).ready(function() {`?

Comment: @Tricky12 Event handler declarations aren't supposed to be wrapped in `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @codenoir All jQuery needs to be wrapped in it, otherwise it may be declared before jQuery has loaded, and will therefor not be attached to the DOM. Hence why he would see a "function does not exist" error. It tries to call the function before jQuery has loaded.

Comment: @Tricky12 not quite, but you keep on thinking that.

Comment: `This will often be a good time to perform tasks that are needed before the user views or interacts with the page, for example to add event handlers and initialize plugins.` - https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: jQuery is included because it gives me the error when I click on leader-btn so that means jQuery is working. I've also wrapped it in the document.ready function but still the same error. Could it be the PHP? I don't think so because it would have given me an error in the php log but instead the error is logged on the console which suggests its the javascript so i don't know.

Comment: For giggles, comment out the .ajax code in your click function and just add an alert.  Does the alert work?

Comment: @Mister Postive I tried the alert and it works fine. So I'm still stumped.

Comment: Include the error message from the console in your question.

Comment: One other thing to try is `jQuery.ajax` instead of `$.ajax`. If you have more libraries included than just jQuery, `$` could potentially be aliased to something else in your code.

Comment: are you using a custom jquery build? also in the console after load, $.ajax() should not be be uncaught type.  jQuery.ajax() is worth checking too.

Comment: figured it out. I was using bootstrap's CDN as well which includes a custom jQuery library which I guess was interfering with my other jQuery CDN. So I essentially changed the order of the links in my <head> by including jQuery CDN before Bootstrap which fixed the issue. Thanks guys for your input.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem.  It turned out that I was using jQuery slim instead of the full library.