# Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function at HTMLTextAreaElement

Tags: jquery, ajax

I kept trying and trying and copying codes from sites, but it always gave that error.
The PHP file exists on the server with that exact name. I checked it million times.

```
  $( "#txt" ).keydown(function() {
    $.ajax({ url: 'updatedatabase.php?content='+$( "#txt" ).val() });
  });
});
```

Comment: jquery library included?

Comment: Type `$.fn.jquery` in the console. It should output the jQuery version you are using. Post the result here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40938704/6521116)

Comment: @rtfm am using bootstrap so it includes jquery library I think

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette 3.1.1 -ajax,-ajax/jsonp,-ajax/load,-ajax/parseXML,-ajax/script,-ajax/var/location,-ajax/var/nonce,-ajax/var/rquery,-ajax/xhr,-manipulation/_evalUrl,-event/ajax,-effects,-effects/animatedSelector,-effects/Tween,-deprecated

Comment: That is the slim version. So many functions, including ajax, are not included. all those `-` signs indicate what is not included.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes the problem was the version thanks a lot it worked

Answer (score -1):

go to chrome dev tools (F12)

go to tab Sources check if jquery is included in you page

check the screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZVIC.jpg

tell me if this helped you ..

Comment: yes i have red the comments just for reference :) , btw thanks

Comment: It was not a answer of this ques

Comment: i believed it is bro because it throws an error stating that $.ajax is not a function which means one of the possible answer is that jquery is not included